# Pull the likes and comments of a post using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.3

I need to pull the likes and comments of a post in Facebook using Graph API. I found out that Facebook does not return the data as a whole but returns in pagination format. 
IS there any way to get the likes ad comments data of a post at once instead of getting in pagination format?
If not is there any other where we can get maximum data per page so that we don't have to loop through many pages to obtain the data?

Please suggest!

Comment: The `limit` parameter allows you to specify how many results you want for one request – but it is also limited to a certain number for different endpoints. After that, you _have_ to use pagination.

Comment: Is there any  way to pull the latest comments? Please advise!

Comment: We don't support reverse chronological ordering on the comments. You'll have to use paging to get the latest comment.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/object/comments