# Is there any way to pull the latest comments and likes from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.3

I am saving a particular media's likes and comments in the database. I am fetching the likes and comments of the media using Graph API every 1 hour  to have the latest data. But Every time I fetch the data using Graph API, I notice that there is no particular order in which the data is returned. The latest comments and likes(new ones) may be returned in the second or the third pagination which is in no particular order.
Is there any way(any particular filter which we can apply) to access the latest likes and comments(new ones) made on a particular media.

Please Advise!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pull the likes and comments of a post using Graph API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30253291/pull-the-likes-and-comments-of-a-post-using-graph-api) – you asked that there already.

Comment: No, that is different.
Here I want to know the method to pull the latest likes and comments

Comment: You added a comment there asking if there was a “way to pull the latest comments”, as a follow-up to my response about the `limit` parameter and pagination. And now here you are asking the same thing. So you should have rather edited your original question IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the since parameter to check for new feeds.  Simply store the updated_time field for the most recent comment you received, and then you can use that time as the since parameter to request the next set of comments.

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/<page-id>/feed?fields=updated_time&since=<last comment received>`